# [Jboss 4.3][Grails 2.3.x] Log does not work properly (ERROR: invalid console appender config detected, console stream is looping)

Tags: grails, jboss, log4j

If we deploy our Grails application in a JBoss 4.3, it always shows the same error message:

```
ERROR: invalid console appender config detected, console stream looping
```

In the `Config.groovy` file we have defined the **log4j**:

```
log4j = {
    root {
        info 'unoAppender','communications', 'hibernate', 'dependencies'
    }

    appenders {
        appender new CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender(
            name:'unoAppender',
            file:'logs/app-uno.log',
            append:true, maxNumberOfDays:60,
            compressBackups:true,
            threshold:Level.DEBUG,
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t:%1X{JSESSION_ID}] [%c{1}] - %m%n"))
            .....
    }
}
```

And also there are appenders in the `jboss-log4j.xml` of the default server.

Finally we have tried to add the following paramenter in the `JAVA_OPTS` of the `run.sh` [`-Dorg.jboss.logging.Log4jService.catchSystemOut=false`] the logs works properly in the console but it does not work in the `server.log`.